# How to apply .otf fonts in fabricJS?

Tags: angular, canvas, fonts, fabricjs, opentype

I have list of .otf fonts, around 200 fonts.

I am loading those fonts using opentype.js as below:

```
opentype.load('HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn.otf', (err, font) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error loading font ', err);
        return
    }
    canvas.getActiveObject().set('fontFamily', 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdCn');
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
});
```

But its not applying any font-family which I am loading from .otf, if I do same thing with .ttf then it is working fine.

Comment: I'm a little confused: what are you using opentype.js for? It looks like all you're doing is "using the font in the canvas", which you don't need opentypejs for at all: load the fonts with a normal `@font-face` and then use the font-family name you set up for each font for the canvas's `context.font = ...`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: thanks for your reply, I did it by injecting dynamic font-face in head tag, and its working fine.

Comment: Then this question should probably be deleted again: by using the conventional approach, things worked fine.

Comment: @Mike: not with the conventional approach it needed to apply some tricks to make it work.

Comment: Then this question still either should be deleted (because you solved this problem on your own - that suggests future people with this problem will, too), or you should write up an answer explaining what you had to do if you think others would benefit from that.

Comment: @mike: thanks mike for your suggestion, I will post my solution here, that way other people can take benefit of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by using this code: first load fonts from server then inject those fonts in head tag of html as font-face:

```
  const a = '<style> @font-face {\n' +
            '    font-family: ' + fontFileName + ';\n' +
            '    src: url(' + url + ') format("opentype");\n' +
            '}</style>';
  $('head').append(a);
```

**url is: blob of font file.**